# Pandas dataframe to Spark dataframe, handling NaN conversions to actual null?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert dataframe from pandas to spark and I am using `spark_context.createDataFrame()` method to create the dataframe. I'm also specifying the schema in the `createDataFrame()` method.

What I want to know is how handle special cases. For example, ***NaN*** in pandas when converted to Spark dataframe ends up being string "NaN". I am looking for ways how to get actual nulls instead of "NaN".

Comment: @help-info.de Your name is so apt.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR** Your best option for now is to skip Pandas completely.

The source of the problem is that Pandas are less expressive than Spark SQL. Spark provides both `NULL` (in a SQL sense, as missing value) and `NaN` (numeric Not a Number).

Pandas from the other handm doesn't have native value which can be used to represent missing values. As a result it uses placeholders like `NaN` / `NaT` or `Inf`, which are indistinguishable to Spark from actual `NaNs` and `Infs` and conversion rules depend on the column type. The only exception are `object` columns (typically strings) which can contain `None` values. You can learn more about handling missing values Pandas from [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html).

> For example, NaN in pandas when converted to Spark dataframe ends up being string "NaN".

This is actually not correct. Depending on type of input column. If column shows `NaN` it is most likely not a number value, not a plain string:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, isnull

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, None], "y": [None, "foo"], 
    "z": [pd.Timestamp("20120101"), pd.Timestamp("NaT")]
})
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

sdf.show()
```

```
+---+----+-------------------+
|  x|   y|                  z|
+---+----+-------------------+
|1.0|null|2012-01-01 00:00:00|
|NaN| foo|               null|
+---+----+-------------------+
```

```py
sdf.select([
    f(c) for c in sdf.columns for f in [isnan, isnull] 
    if (f, c) != (isnan, "z")  # isnan cannot be applied to timestamp 
]).show()
```

```
+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|isnan(x)|(x IS NULL)|isnan(y)|(y IS NULL)|(z IS NULL)|
+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|   false|      false|   false|       true|      false|
|    true|      false|   false|      false|       true|
+--------+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

In practice, parallelized local collections (including Pandas objects) have negligible importance beyond simple testing and toy examples so you can always convert data manually (skipping possible Arrow optimizations):

```
import numpy as np

spark.createDataFrame([
   tuple(
        None if isinstance(x, (float, int)) and np.isnan(x) else x
        for x in record.tolist())
   for record in pdf.to_records(index=False)
], pdf.columns.tolist()).show()
```

```
+----+----+-------------------+
|   x|   y|                  z|
+----+----+-------------------+
| 1.0|null|1325376000000000000|
|null| foo|               null|
+----+----+-------------------+
```

If missing / not-a-number ambiguity is not an issue then just load data as usually and replace in Spark.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when 

sdf.select([
    when(~isnan(c), col(c)).alias(c) if t in ("double", "float") else c 
    for c, t in sdf.dtypes
]).show()
```

```
+----+----+-------------------+
|   x|   y|                  z|
+----+----+-------------------+
| 1.0|null|2012-01-01 00:00:00|
|null| foo|               null|
+----+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: This also helps if you have 'NaT' in a datetime64[ns] field and want to transfer it to spark (as in my case). Very helpful answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for a comprehensive explanation. Different treatment of (pandas's) None for numeric and string columns in Spark was surprising to me.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to load a pandas df you can replace NaN with None:

```
import pandas as pd
def load_csv(spark, path):
    """read csv to spark df"""
    pd_df = pd.read_csv(path)
    pd_df = pd_df.where((pd.notnull(pd_df)), None)
    df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
    return df
```

Comment: simple and efficient!

Comment: Can simplify the `where` line: `pd_df.where(cond=df.notna(), other=None)`.

Comment: Nice solution! This should really be internal to `spark.createDataFrame`. There does seem to be [trouble](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30966) with this solution when the input pd_df has had `.convert_dtypes()` called on it. Also seems not always to work when `spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled` is `true`.