# PySpark DataFrames - filtering using comparisons between columns of different types

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose you have a dataframe with columns of various types (string, double...) and a special value "miss" that represents "missing value" in string-typed columns.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

pdf = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 'miss'],
    [2, 'x'],
    [None, 'y']
], columns=['intcol', 'strcol'])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=pdf)
```

I am trying to count the number of non-missing values for each column, using filtering like this:

```py
col = df['strcol']
df.filter(col.isNotNull() & (col != 'miss')).show()
```

Which works for the string column:

```
+------+------+
|intcol|strcol|
+------+------+
|   2.0|     x|
|   NaN|     y|
+------+------+
```

However, for the numeric column, it filters out all the rows:

```py
col = df['intcol']
df.filter(col.isNotNull() & (col != 'miss')).show()
```

```
+------+------+
|intcol|strcol|
+------+------+
+------+------+
```

It seems like this is because the cross-type comparison of the numeric column with string value results in all-null values:

```py
df.select(df['intcol'] != 'miss').show()
```

```
+---------------------+
|(NOT (intcol = miss))|
+---------------------+
|                 null|
|                 null|
|                 null|
+---------------------+
```

Which I find a bit unexpected (e.g. `1 != ''` is True, not null in "normal" Python)

My **question** is really several questions:

- why does the cross type comparison results in nulls?
- what is the best way to test for equality/non-equality across different types in the "expected way"? Or (in my case) do I need to include separate logic that switches based on the type of the column?
- It seems like `df.filter(~df['intcol'].isin(['miss']))` does the job, but I wonder if that is less efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with why. `DataFrame` API is a DSL for SQL and SQL evaluation rules apply. Whenever you apply an operator on objects of different types, `CAST` operation is applied, according to predefined rules, on an operand of lower precedence. In general numeric types, have higher precedence, therefore (following the execution plan `df.select(df['intcol'] != 'miss').explain(True)`):

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [NOT (intcol#0 = miss) AS (NOT (intcol = miss))#12]
+- LogicalRDD [intcol#0, strcol#1], false
```

is rewritten as

```
== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
(NOT (intcol = miss)): boolean
Project [NOT (intcol#0 = cast(miss as double)) AS (NOT (intcol = miss))#12]
+- LogicalRDD [intcol#0, strcol#1], false
```

where `'miss'` is `CASTED` to `double`, and later converted to `NULL`

```
== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [null AS (NOT (intcol = miss))#22]
+- LogicalRDD [intcol#0, strcol#1], false
```

as cast with this operand is undefined.

Since equality with `NULL` is undefined as well - [Difference between === null and isNull in Spark DataDrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41533290/10465355) - `filter` yields an empty result.

Now how to address that. Both explicit casting:

```
df.filter(df['intcol'].cast("string") != 'miss')
```

and null safe equality:

```
df.filter(~df['intcol'].cast("string").eqNullSafe('miss'))
```

should do the trick.

Also please note that `NaN` values are not `NULL` and conversion via Pandas is lossy - [Pandas dataframe to Spark dataframe, handling NaN conversions to actual null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45181768/10465355)