# How Spark calculates mean and stddev of string column

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following data (just showing a snippet)

```
DEST_COUNTRY_NAME   ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME count
United States   Romania 15
United States   Croatia 1
United States   Ireland 344
Egypt   United States   15
```

I read it with `inferSchema` option set to `true` and then `describe` the columns. It seem to work fine.

```
scala> val data = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("./data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv")
scala> data.describe().show()
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|summary|DEST_COUNTRY_NAME|ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME|             count|
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|  count|              256|                256|               256|
|   mean|             null|               null|       1770.765625|
| stddev|             null|               null|23126.516918551915|
|    min|          Algeria|             Angola|                 1|
|    max|           Zambia|            Vietnam|            370002|
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

If I don't specify `inferSchema`, then all the columns are treated as string.

```
scala> val dataNoSchema = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("./data/flight-data/csv/2015-summary.csv")
dataNoSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string, ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string ... 1 more field]

scala> dataNoSchema.printSchema
root
 |-- DEST_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- count: string (nullable = true)
```

Question 1) Why do then `Spark` gives `mean` and `stddev` values for the last column `count`

```
scala> dataNoSchema.describe().show();
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|summary|DEST_COUNTRY_NAME|ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME|             count|
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
|  count|              256|                256|               256|
|   mean|             null|               null|       1770.765625|
| stddev|             null|               null|23126.516918551915|
|    min|          Algeria|             Angola|                 1|
|    max|           Zambia|            Vietnam|               986|
+-------+-----------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Question 2 ) If `Spark` now interprets `count` as `numeric` column then why the `max` value is 986 and not 37002 (as is in data DataFrame)

Answer (score 0):

Spark SQL aspires to be SQL standard compliant, therefore uses the same evaluation rules, and if needed, transparently coerces types to satisfy the expression (see for example [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459686/10465355)   to [PySpark DataFrames - filtering using comparisons between columns of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54458070/10465355)).

It means that `max` and `mean` / `stddev` cases are simply not equivalent:

- maximum is meaningful for strings (with [lexicographic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)) and no coercion is required

  ```scala
  Seq.empty[String].toDF("count").agg(max("count")).explain
  ```

  ```
  == Physical Plan ==
  SortAggregate(key=[], functions=[max(count#69)])
  +- Exchange SinglePartition
     +- SortAggregate(key=[], functions=[partial_max(count#69)])
        +- LocalTableScan <empty>, [count#69]
  ```
- average or standard deviation are not, and the argument is casted to double

  ```scala
  Seq.empty[String].toDF("count").agg(mean("count")).explain
  ```

  ```
  == Physical Plan ==
  *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[avg(cast(count#81 as double))])
  +- Exchange SinglePartition
     +- *(1) HashAggregate(keys=[], functions=[partial_avg(cast(count#81 as double))])
        +- LocalTableScan <empty>, [count#81].
  ```

Comment: It is not. I am saying that `max` with `String` argument uses [lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), because such operation is defined, and doesn't require casting.